# Favicon not showing up in Google Chrome browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

For some reason my favicon is not showing up on my chrome tab. From all the articles I have read I am writing the code correctly. It does work in Firefox. I also cleared my cache and tried an incognito window and am still not seeing it.

When I go to:
localhost:8080/favicon.ico
I do see the favicon.

Here is my code within the HTML header:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 64x64" 
href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png" />
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What does the console say in Chrome Dev tools? Does it say anything about the favicon?

Comment: Also I would suggest taking a look at this tool: http://realfavicongenerator.net/ It will help you set up the favicon for multiple devices.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović I do not see any errors in the console.

Comment: @nejc.m thanks for the site.  For classic browsers here is what I see the errors are: 1) image is ill-formed 2) favicon.ico is missing some icons of recommended sizes (16x16, 32x32, 48x48) 3) favicon.ico does not contain the highest resolution icon (48x48)

Comment: That's why generate it on the site. Provide a big enough logo/image and it will generate all the images and code for you.

Comment: @nejc.m I generated the code and copy and pasted it into my head tag in my index.html . Still not showing up on google chrome :( If you want check out the website maybe you can find an error: www.curedash.com

Comment: So I don't see the new code on the site. So how the tool works is that you provide the icon/logo (best if at least 500x500). Then you apply all the needed settings (bg color for mobile icon...) then it generates the code and provides you the favicon package which is a zip with all the needed icons which needs to be extracted and all the icons need to be uploaded to your server. Be careful because the path to the image in the code has to match the path of your image on the server.

Comment: @nejc.m Here is the code it generated for me. `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
 <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
 <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">`

Comment: That looks more like it. So put this into you head section and don't forget to download the package from the site that contains all the icons specified in the code. You need to upload these icons to your server now and adjust the href attribute in the code accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Try doing a favicon cache reset as explained in #3 [here](http://www.nullalo.com/en/how-to-delete-google-chrome-favicon-cache/)

> 3. FAVICON CACHE RESET
>
> A more drastic way to solve the problem, but that allows you to do it
>   globally rather than site-by-site, is to clear the browser’s favicon
>   cache. The procedure is:
>
> - on Mac: delete the following file
>
>   ```
>   ${user.home}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Favicons
>   ```
> - on Windows: delete Favicons-journal and Favicons files from the following location
>
>   ```
>   C:\Users\nomeutente\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
>   ```
>
> In both cases, a browser restart is suggested.

Answer (score 5):

You should link your `favicon.ico` like below:

```
<link rel="icon" href="wherever/your_icon/is?v=1.0" />
```

The thing is that, chrome could not find it for the first time and now it's assuming you don't have one as it renders from cache. The `?v=1.0` part makes sure that chrome loads it again.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution worked right away!

Comment: this is so clever! had not idea this existed, worked like a charm.

Comment: I did everything else, clearing the "Cache", "Site Data", Chrome cache,  Favicon-journal & Favicons files but none worked except this "?v=random string". Cheers and a very big thanks to @Plabon Dutta !!

Answer (score 1):

right-click on file (the favicon), go to properties, look towards the bottom and you will see attributes and the option to unblock the file, and unblock it. Worked immediately with browser-sync Blind luck, I wasn't even expecting it to be there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have all of that extra icon formatting that isn't really needed. My icons only look like this: `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">`. I would suggest you try that (unless the rest is absolutely needed). Also, it is possible that it just isn't loading properly. Whenever I set up my icons, depending on what I do it on (server or by clicking on index.html file), sometimes I have to reload it a few times.

Comment: I just had the extra formatting seeing if it changed anything. I refactored my code to what you put and getting the same result of it working in Firefox but not chrome :/

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. I have tried most suggestions, including; changing icon name, deleting chrome's local favicons file, ico and png formats, clearing cache. No joy with any of these attempts to fix.

I have 2 projects with same header and it works with 1 icon but not the other? It works in IE but will not work in chrome. I'm convinced it is to do with the Chrome Favicons-journal but not sure how to prove it.

Will reinstall Chrome and see how that goes :(

Comment: I gave up on the issue but recently got a new computer and loaded the code and it worked, my guess it was a cacheing issue. Maybe try an incognito window or reseting cache in google chrome by opening inspected and right clicking on refresh button

Comment: Thanks Emil, If it is working on client pcs then it's all good. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had tried a lot different things. My 1 machine kept showing them wrong, but they were fine on all my other machines. I even deleted my entire:

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

Folder and copied one from a working machine.  When I first launched Chrome, they were fine... but went bad again soon after.

Then I noticed that every time I'd launch a bookmark from Chrome on my Android phone, the icon on my bad machine would come back.  But it seemed like I first needed to click on the bad bookmark, then navigate elsewhere, before it updated my bad machine (not 100% sure of this).

So anyway, I just went through all my bad bookmarks through my phone, and they all came back on my bad machine.

Now, I'm almost certain I had tried the same process from a good PC, but didn't work.  Again, I'm not 100% certain of this.

Hopefully, this can be tested with others.